# Use default title text view style for customize title text in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, material-design, android-toolbar

I am implementing material design in my app with toolbar item. In my toolbar I have add "imageview" and "textview" and replace the title text for my "textView"

Here my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
local:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" >

<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<ImageView
   android:id="@+id/logo_image"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
   android:src="@drawable/app"
   android:layout_centerVertical="true"
   android:scaleType="centerInside" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/logo_image"

   />

 </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

here above textview i have to set textsize, color, textstyle all those thinks,

```
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="#fff"
```

But I need to set default title text style here, How can do this?, please give some idea

Answer (score 8):

You can achieve this with

> style="@style/TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title"

```
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/title_activity_login"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title"
            />
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this can help. Here is the implementation of [`Toolbar`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.java) form the Android Support Library v7 source code,

```
     /**
     * Set the title of this toolbar.
     *
     * <p>A title should be used as the anchor for a section of content. It should
     * describe or name the content being viewed.</p>
     *
     * @param title Title to set
     */
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(title)) {
            if (mTitleTextView == null) {
                final Context context = getContext();
                mTitleTextView = new TextView(context);
                mTitleTextView.setSingleLine();
                mTitleTextView.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
                if (mTitleTextAppearance != 0) {
                    mTitleTextView.setTextAppearance(context, mTitleTextAppearance);
                }
                if (mTitleTextColor != 0) {
                    mTitleTextView.setTextColor(mTitleTextColor);
                }
            }
            if (mTitleTextView.getParent() == null) {
                addSystemView(mTitleTextView);
                updateChildVisibilityForExpandedActionView(mTitleTextView);
            }
        } else if (mTitleTextView != null && mTitleTextView.getParent() != null) {
            removeView(mTitleTextView);
        }
        if (mTitleTextView != null) {
            mTitleTextView.setText(title);
        }
        mTitleText = title;
    }
```

You can use this to set the styles of your `TextView`.

Answer (score -2):

use these in your textview xml:

```
android:textSize="20sp"
android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
android:singleLine="true"
android:ellipsize="end"
```